# Dojo: Select element by tag name inside a div selected by ID

Tags: dojo, selector

I am looking for an equivalent in Dojo for this jQuery  selector
$(">fieldset, #d1") or ("#d1 fieldset")

```
<div id="d1">
 <span> 
   <fieldset>abc</fieldset> 
 </span>
</div>
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dojo/query` module seems to be what you want.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/query.html